# Button in TextBox disappears when selecting text while Windows media player plays music

Tags: vb.net, windows

This is my first question, please be nice. Oh, and I'm not a native english speaker. :)

I've discovered some weird bug in my application. I've created a TextBox control with a button in it (code below). Following these steps will make the button disappear.

1. Start windows media player with some music (or video)
2. Start the application
3. Click in TextBox control and hold down left mouse button
4. Move your cursor around like crazy
5. Woosh... Button disappears.

This will not happen when you closed or paused your windows media player. I was able to reproduce this bug on a different system (Windows 7 and Windows 10). This is totally weird, because it doesn't seem logical. Windows is doing crazy stuff with the windows media player...

I'm not sure if there's a workaround. Can anybody help me with this or should I ask on Microsoft forums? I've tried to call "UpdateButton" while selection changed, but I wasn't successful.

```
Public Class TextBoxEx
    Inherits TextBox

    Const BUTTON_WIDTH As Integer = 18
    Const EM_SETMARGINS As Integer = &HD3
    Const EC_RIGHTMARGIN As Integer = &H2

    <Runtime.InteropServices.DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError:=True)> _
    Private Shared Function SendMessage(ByVal hWnd As IntPtr, ByVal Msg As UInteger, ByVal wParam As Integer, ByVal lParam As Integer) As IntPtr
    End Function

    Private btnCommand As Button
    Public Sub New()
        btnCommand = New Button
        btnCommand.Cursor = Cursors.Default
        btnCommand.Image = My.Resources.iconCancel

        Me.Controls.Add(btnCommand)
        Call UpdateButton()
    End Sub

    Private Sub UpdateButton()
        Dim rightMargin As Integer = (BUTTON_WIDTH + 1) << 16
        btnCommand.Size = New Size(BUTTON_WIDTH, Me.ClientSize.Height)
        btnCommand.Location = New Point(Me.ClientSize.Width - BUTTON_WIDTH, 0)
        Call SendMessage(Me.Handle, EM_SETMARGINS, EC_RIGHTMARGIN, rightMargin)
    End Sub

    Protected Overrides Sub OnResize(e As System.EventArgs)
        MyBase.OnResize(e)
        Call UpdateButton()
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: Don't put a button inside a text box. They will have painting fights. (Media Player is probably triggering extra repaints.)

Comment: Just following up with what Raymond said about painting conflicts, why would you need a button in a textbox? Just create a custom control with a text box and a button. You can design it so the button still appears as if it's inside the textbox by removing the textbox border and wrapping the textbox and button in another bordered control like a white panel. Then you don't have to do all the SendMessage stuff you're doing with the margins.

Comment: I was going to inherit from a TextBox, because I wanted to expose all the properties of a TextBox without writing too much own code. Maybe I should follow you advices and create an usercontrol for this. Still weird in my opinion! Thanks anyways.